# Testing if elements in a list are within a list of ranges

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to check if a list of resistors can be used to achieve a set of equivalent resistances. (Reciprocal of the sum of the reciprocals of the individual resistors is the equivalent resistance) Achieving the exact value of equivalent resistance is very tough, so I would like to allow a tolerance of 5% max. privArrayTest generates a list of all combinations of the resistors and calculates the equivalence. I attempted to implement the tolerance with tolerance[x_], and run that through ContainsAll, but it appears to just be checking the edge values rather than values within the range.

```
ParallelResist[arrayInTest_, arrayInCompare_] :=
 Module[{privArrayTest, invert, sum, privArrayC, tolerance},
  (*internal functions*)
  invert[x_] := x^-1;
  sum[x_] := Total[x];
  tolerance[x_] := {x - x*.05, x + x*.05};

  (*main body*)
  privArrayTest = Map[invert, N[Map[sum, Subsets[Map[invert, arrayInTest], {1, \[Infinity]}]]]];
  (*1,\[Infinity] prevents the first blank subset from being \generated*)

  privArrayC = Map[tolerance, arrayInCompare];
  Print[privArrayC]; (*Debugging Code*)
  Print["Debug code,privArrayTest", privArrayTest];(*Debugging code*)

  (*compare code, returns true false*)
  ContainsAll[privArrayTest, privArrayC]
  ]
```

Example input:

```
resistors = {1500, 1000, 2500, 20000};
equivalence = {472.441, 483.871, 895.522};
```

Example output:

```
{{448.819,496.063},{459.677,508.065},{850.746,940.298}}

Debug code,privArrayTest{1500.,1000.,2500.,20000.,600.,937.5,1395.35,714.286,952.381,2222.22,483.871,582.524,895.522,689.655,472.441}

True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContainsAll` checks whether expressions contain other expressions on a *pattern matching* level. It does not check containment in intervals.

Maybe this helps?

```
tol = 0.05;

possibleresistances = 1/Total[1/Rest@subsets, {2}];
A = Outer[
   {equiv, resistance} \[Function] Between[resistance, (1 + {-1, 1} tol) equiv],
   equivalence,
   possibleresistances
   ];

And @@ Or @@@ A
```

> True

Comment: Some alternatives: 1. `possibleresistances = HarmonicMean[#]/Length[#] & /@ subsets` 2. the main testing function can be done as `{equiv, resistance} \[Function] Between[resistance, (1 + {-1, 1} tol) equiv]`.

Comment: Hi @J.M. Good points. However, it appears to me that `HarmonicMean` is somewhat inefficient (which does matter in this scenario).

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. What about `1/Total[1/subsets, {2}]`?

Comment: That's better! Thank you!

Comment: So the main issue is I need the possible resistances contain each member of the equivalence list(+-5%) at least once for the possible resistances to be a successful list. The code I have works, albeit not the best written, except for looking through the ranges of acceptable tolerance. I was able to use ContainsAll when I matched the machine precision (without the tolerance), so I am looking for a replacement command, if one exists.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken with my previous comment. It works! Thank you very much! I was mis-reading your solution, I don't follow exactly how this works, but I will look into that! I will let you know in a couple hours when I am done sorting my dataset if everything worked.

Comment: You're welcome!